# When is the aux file read and written?

Tags: auxiliary-files

1. I'd like to know when the `aux` file is read. I know it happens after the preamble, but does it come before or after the `\AtBeginDocument` hook?
2. I'd like to know when the `aux` file (or any other helper file) is actually written. I tried to trace the writing process by placing an undefined command after something should have been written to the `aux` file, and run `pdflatex` in interactive mode, like so:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   \section{S}\label{s}% write something to the aux file

   \foo% unknown command
   \end{document}
   ```

   but to my surprise the `aux` file is still empty when `pdflatex` stops at the error. I guess there is some buffering happening, but how would I resolve the synchronization issue? Say, when `\foo` is command that wants to read from the `aux` file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `.aux` file is read as part of the `\document` macro (`\begin{document}`) but *before* the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is used. (You can check this by inserting some 'test code' into the `.aux` file and the hook.)

Writing to the `.aux` file takes place both 'immediately' and at shipout. The latter is important to get for example the correct page numbers for cross-references, so things like `\label` take place in a delayed fashion, using the `\protected@write` 'wrapper' around the `\write` primitive. Thus for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\foo}
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\baz}

\end{document}
```

only places `\foo` in the `.aux` file: `\baz` is never written as there is no page shipout. In your example, shipout occurs after `\foo`, so you see nothing in the `.aux` file at that point although a shipout does occur later.

Note that TeX keeps the `.aux` file open until the end of the run, so you cannot be sure that any particular `\write` will appear in the partial `.aux` file during a run. As such, the only safe time to check on what gets written to the file is after the run completes. In particular, badly-terminated jobs may leave the `.aux` file in an incomplete state even if the crash occurs after writes 'should' have taken place.

Comment: Thanks. But even when I do a `\clearpage` after the `\label`, and pdflatex tells me it shipped out the first page before running into the error, I still don't see anything in the `aux` file. Why?

Comment: @mafp A `\clearpage` does nothing if there's no material to build a page.

Comment: Because the file is still open for writing. It is closed only at `\end{document}`

Comment: @egreg But the section title is there, is that not enough? I mean, it says `[1{/var/lib/texmf/fo
nts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \foo`, that is the shipout of the first page, no?

Comment: @mafp: No, the page shipout routine of Tex runs _asynchronously_. So even if the page is finished, it is not processed immediately.

Comment: @Daniel: The problem bothering @mafp has imho nothing to do with asynchronously output. The file is still open and so its content - even if it belongs to previous pages lurks still around in memory and you don't see it if you open the file. If one would add `\makeatletter\immediate\closeout\@mainaux` before the error it would appear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Well, that is asynchronous output on another level, isn't it :-) If `tex` has already invoked the operating system's `write()` syscall, it may well be the case that the file system is buffering the content until the final `close()`. However, this depends on the OS and using another file system could change this behaviour. However, if `tex` itself does some internal buffering (I don't know the implementation details) and delays the `write()` syscall until the `\closeout\@mainaux`, I would consider it as asynchronous output by `tex`.

Comment: Joseph -- please add the information to your answer that tex doesn't *close* the `.aux` file until the very end.  as it stands now, unless someone reads @UlrikeFischer's comments, they might still think that they should be able to see a partial `.aux` file if their job crashes 99% of the way through a long job, but they can't.

Comment: If the people who rejected [my edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/169215) understood a 10th of this helpful post, they would have realized that **even if a page were shipped out, the code in [the answer as of 2019-04-14](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/120978/revisions) wouldn't write `\baz` to the `.aux` file.** This is because `\protected@write` is quite different from `\write`. `\protected@write` takes **3 args** and the 3rd one is subject to `\edef` before `\write`. One could write `\baz` with `\protected@write\@auxout{}{\protect\baz}` (+ put a box on page).

Comment: @frougon I'e made the edit: sorry about the missing argument

Comment: @frougon I've kept both arguments as `\noexpand` as the idea is to show as little difference as possible

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thanks, I was going to point out the problem with `\noexpand` (i.e., if the page were non-empty, `\protected@write` would write the *expansion* of `\baz` but not the `\baz` token), but if it's on purpose, okay. :)