# How and when is the "aux" file read and processed?

Tags: auxiliary-files

Note:  I've already looked at [When is the aux file read and written?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120973/22413), but it doesn't address the issues I'm curious about.

I wrote some commands for tracking information in my document.  Since I would like to have this information available from the beginning of the document, I felt the best way to store this information would be to write it the `aux` file.  In the process of debugging, I noticed---what seemed to me---a few odd things about what was happening with the `aux` file.

In particular, it seems that the `aux` file is processed twice: once at the beginning of the document when it is read in and again at the end when it is closed.  What I'm confused about is that when the `aux` file is closed, it appears to execute the commands I've written to the `aux` file.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% uncommenting this next line seems to affect what gets dumped into my
%% document before processing is completed.                            
% \usepackage[paperheight=3in,paperwidth=2in,margin=0.25in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{aecounter}

\makeatletter
%% A command to retrieve the logged page number, a user into value,  
%% and a counter value from the 'aux' file.                          
%% #1=page number                                                    
%% #2=value of what was passed to \aelogdata                          
%% #3=counter value at time that  \aelogdata was called               
\def\aedocumentdata#1#2#3{%%
   \ifcsname aepage#1value\endcsname\relax
     \expandafter\xdef\csname aepage#1value\endcsname{\number\numexpr\csname aepage#1value\endcsname+#2}
     \typeout{-[#1:#2]-->\csname aepage#1value\endcsname}%%
   \else
     \typeout{--------------------------------------------------------------------}
     \typeout{-[#1:#2]-->#2}%%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname aepage#1value\endcsname{#2}%%
   \fi
}

%% logger to write information to 'aux' file.
\newcommand\aelogdata[1]{%%
  \stepcounter{aecounter}%%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%%
    \string\aedocumentdata{\number\value{page}}
                        {#1}
                        {\number\value{aecounter}}}%%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\aegetloggedinformation{%%
  \ifcsname aepage\number\value{page}value\endcsname
    [page \thepage] : value is \csname aepage\number\value{page}value\endcsname
  \else
    NOT DEFINED
  \fi
}

\AtBeginDocument{\typeout{----------BEGIN DOC----------}}
\AtEndDocument{\typeout{---------- END  DOC ----------}}
%% I alter the definition 
\AtEndDocument{\def\aedocumentdata#1#2#3{DOES THIS CREEP INTO MY FILE?\par\vspace{1cm}\typeout{<<page #1-->the #3th input value was `#2'>>}}}
%% But here, I nevertheless can manage to input something into my document   
\AtEndDocument{\par\vspace{\fill}\centering\rule{0.15in}{0.4pt} HELLO WORLD \rule{0.15in}{0.4pt}\par}
\AtEndDocument{\par\vspace{\fill}\centering\rule{0.15in}{0.4pt} BYE WORLD   \rule{0.15in}{0.4pt}\par}
\begin{document}

\aegetloggedinformation

\aelogdata{2}
\aelogdata{3}
\aelogdata{1}

\pagebreak

\aegetloggedinformation

\aelogdata{5}
\aelogdata{3}
\aelogdata{2}

\pagebreak

\aegetloggedinformation

\aelogdata{1}
\aelogdata{1}
\aelogdata{1}

\end{document}
```

I was not expecting to see the `\typeout` control sequences executed at the end of the document (in fact, it took me quite a while to figure out where they were cropping up from).  A bit of tweaking and I discovered that my `aux` file seems to be executed as if LaTeX were innocuously reading one final `\input` request.

A bit more playing around with the page geometry, and I got a few more surprises.  If I seemed to set the geometry *just right*, then this final apparent `\input` wasn't so *innocuous* after all.

Could someone explain why my commands in the `aux` file seem to be executed before the write stream is closed (if that is what's happening)?  Also, why does the *input* sometimes creep into my document and sometimes not?

Regarding the effect of the geometry.

With

```
\usepackage[paperheight=6in,paperwidth=3in,margin=0.25in]{geometry}
```

my last page looks like:

[image]

But with

```
\usepackage[paperheight=3in,paperwidth=2in,margin=0.25in]{geometry}
```

my last page looks like:

[image]

Comment: Commands are executed both in the first reading and at end document.

Comment: @egreg So is there a way to inhibit that behavior at the end of the document (other than make sure the commands work rather innocuously)?

Comment: @egreg Or perhaps a better question is:  why is this the preferred approach at the end of the document? (I can easily work around it by `\let`ting my commands to `\relax` in the `\AtEndDocument` hook.)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, LaTeX does `\input{filename.aux}` as part of `\enddocument`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4057:
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     [...]
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

As you see, `\@enddocumenthook` is executed previously, so instructions given through `\AtEndDocument` are processed at that point, when  typesetting has not yet been inhibited; so, if you have `\AtEndDocument{foo}`, the word is printed. However, typesetting text with `\AtEndDocument` is not recommended at all: the final instruction in `\enddocument` essentially flushes whatever is possibly remaining in the main vertical list. If something in the vertical list, added with `\AtEndDocument` produces a full page, this happens *before* that instruction, so a page is created (but probably this is not what you want).

Typesetting text before the `aux` file is closed and read back in can be done with the help of the `atveryend` package, that provides more hooks.

LaTeX doesn't input the `.aux` file when `\if@filesw` is set to false (by the `\nofiles` command). Macros are processed as usual.

It's good programming disabling macros that aren't used for consistency checks (so `\newlabel` isn't disabled, but given a different definition) and `\AtEndDocument{\renewcommand...}` is the right tool for this.

Comment: Any idea about why the different output depending upon my page geometry?

Comment: @A.Ellett I see nothing particularly strange; what are you referring to?

Comment: If I uncomment my `\usepackage[...]{geometry}` line, I get different output from the `aux` file, but not for every page geometry.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the different geometries I've experimented with and the resulting last page of the document.

Comment: package [atveryend](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) provides convenient hooks into `\enddocument`.

Comment: For additional information and fine grained control over the moment at which an enddocument hook is executed, the `atveryend` package may be useful. (See documentation.)

Answer (score 4):

latex is not expecting the aux file to typeset text, it is input to check cross references *after* the final `\clearpage` that flushes all text and floats.

So any text that is typeset to the main vertical list is likely to be lost unless (as with your short page version) you typeset enough to trigger a "natural" page break in which case (just) the text before the page break will be output.

Comment: That is useful to know.