# tikzpagenodes gives bad output on the arxiv

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, geometry, arxiv, tikzpagenodes

I'm using `tikzpagenodes` to detect text boundaries around my page (I use it in a more complex way than drawing this frame, but let's simply draw a frame for now):

[image]

My issue is that on the arXiv, the box is not drawn correctly (you can easily test it yourself by [starting to add a new article](https://arxiv.org), arXiv will display a preview of the pdf before filling the title/authors…):

[image]

I was thinking that it might be a difference of version, but even trying with tex 2020 like the arXiv works… so it seems like arXiv is doing something weird here. I also tried to upload the latest version from the `geometry` package (tikzpagenodes has not changed for 10 years so it should already be at the latest version), but same issue again…

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
% Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Output encoding https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677. Important to copy accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.4in, bottom=1.4in, right=1in, left=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw (current page text area.north west) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Log from the arXiv:

```
Output written on debug_2.dvi (2 pages, 18.02 KB).
  All output files are converted to PDF for previewing.

If you are attempting to compile with a specific engine (PDFLaTeX, LaTeX,
TeX) please carefully review the appropriate log below.

Summary of attempted TeX compilation runs:

  Processing;'debug_2.tex'
    Running hlatex for first time.
    Running hlatex for second time.

  Last run per file and engine
    debug_2.tex:
      Last run for engine hlatex is second

Key for Highlighted AutoTeX Log:
Severe warnings/errors.'
Warnings deemed important'
General warnings/errors from packages.'
Warnings/Errors deemed unimportant. Example: undefined references in first TeX run.'
Indicates positive event, does not guarantee overall success
Informational markup
References to arXiv help pages or other documentation.
Highlighted AutoTeX Log:

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <debug_2.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <geometry.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'debug_2.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4768457/ && latex 'debug_2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./debug_2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)) (./geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.
def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
No file debug_2.aux.
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

[1] [2] (./debug_2.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `debug_2.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

)
Output written on debug_2.dvi (2 pages, 18452 bytes).
Transcript written on debug_2.log.

[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4768457/ && latex 'debug_2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./debug_2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)) (./geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.
def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(./debug_2.aux)
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./debug_2.out) (./debug_2.out) [1] [2] (./debug_2.aux) )
Output written on debug_2.dvi (2 pages, 18452 bytes).
Transcript written on debug_2.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'debug_2.aux' (1678095050 >= 1678095048)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'debug_2.out' (1678095050 >= 1678095048)
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'debug_2.dvi'
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4768457/ && dvips -R2 -z 'debug_2.dvi' -o )" 2>&1
[verbose]: dvi(h)ps said ...
This is dvips(k) 2020.1 Copyright 2020 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2023.03.06:0930' -> debug_2.ps
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texc.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/hps.pro>.
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>[1] [2]
<./head.tmp><./body.tmp>
.
[verbose]: Backing up 'debug_2.ps'. Going to change %%Title line.
[verbose]: %%Title: line found and changed.
[verbose]: Title change completed.
[verbose]: Backing up 'debug_2.ps'. Going to add a name/date stamp to it.
[verbose]: OK, inserting the stamp
[verbose]: Stamping completed.
[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: Processing DVI
[verbose]: Gzipping and moving debug_2.dvi
[verbose]: Gzipping ...4768457/debug_2.dvi
[verbose]: Processing postscript
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for debug_2.dvi
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for debug_2.dvi.gz
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for debug_2.ps
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for debug_2.tex
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for geometry.sty
[verbose]: Gzipping ...4768457/debug_2.ps
[verbose]: Moving .../4768457/debug_2.ps.gz => .../4768457/tex_cache/4768457.ps.gz

[verbose]: Moving .../4768457/debug_2.dvi.gz => .../4768457/tex_cache/4768457.dvi.gz

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Related to [Use "precompiled" aux file to avoid limits on the arxiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678060/use-precompiled-aux-file-to-avoid-limits-on-the-arxiv?noredirect=1#comment1683078_678060)

Comment: what is `/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg` doing....

Comment: what happens if you include an empty geometry.cfg  in the submission?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, so I get exactly the same (bad) pdf, the log are here: https://pastebin.com/y1LUwWvf (I can't paste them here as overleaf complains that the file is too big)

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, that was the only file not from 2020/texmf-dist.  You could add `\listfiles` and compare package versions between their tl2020 and yours,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thanks, I didn't know this command. So I get this https://pastebin.com/3wDPFbgF, I can just see that mine 2020 is a bit more recent… By any chance is it possible to automatically extract all the files needed to compile a document/and or display the absolute path to the files, so that I upload them directly online? (and if I do, is there a chance it works, or could it break the engine if I mix different versions?

Comment: there are some scripts but  you really don't want to be uploading an entire tikz/pgf for example. Probably easier to hide that it's made by tex and just submit the pdf

Comment: `display the absolute path to the files` the log file has all the absolute paths, that's how I spotted the cfg earlier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by arXiv's default behavior of first running through latex, and autotex not allowing dynamic figure conversion. So things like a pgf/tikz image may or may not function at all (or as expected) under plain latex. However, this is completely ameliorated by using pdflatex instead of latex. This can be forced in arXiv by setting the `pdfoutput` flag to 1:

```
\pdfoutput=1
```

as the first line of your tex, which forces it out of dvi-mode. Adding that one line to your MWE, I now get the expected output. You may also want to explicitly add `a4paper` to your call to your class (as I did for the screen shot), as without this explicit call, arXiv will likely try and place geometry's page size on letter-sized paper, [as explained in our help pages](https://info.arxiv.org/help/faq/dvips.html).

[image: image output from MWE provided by user with added 1-line fix]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I did suspect that dvi could be an issue, but I did some tests locally with DVI and it was working fine even with latex 2020… but I was not expecting arxiv's autotex to bring some dark magic in the game. Thanks!

Comment: it likely was working locally because your tex may automatically call a figure conversion package such as [`eps2pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) which in arXiv has been converted to a no-op, and local tex occasionally allow for a `shell-escape`, which is also disabled in arXiv as a security vulnerability.