# Output of aux file from standalone with subpreambles contains undefined command

Tags: overleaf, standalone, pgfgantt

Was: **Document starts with dimension as text**

I'm using `pgfgantt` in a file in a subdirectory, which is included using the `standalone` subpreambles feature. However, the textual value of a dimension is somehow being inserted right at the start of my document, and the document is failing to compile

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}

Before

\input{main/gantt.tex}

\end{document}
```

`main/gantt.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid={*1{dotted}},
    x unit=4mm,
    y unit chart=8mm,
    y unit title=4mm,
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    time slot unit=month,
    title height=1
    ]{2020-06}{2022-12}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Result of building `main.tex`:

```
l.3 \gtt@chartextrasize
                       {0}{0.4pt}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Overleaf's preview:

[image]

Why is `00.4pt` appearing in the output? Where did it come from?

---

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, this failed to compile.

If I add `\usepackage{pgfgantt}` to `main.tex`, then the error and the dimension go away.

Why is this necessary?

Comment: Are you sure your main.tex compiles without error? Because Overleaf is setup to always give a PDF even if there are compilation errors. But in order to do that LaTeX have to make guesses when there are compilation errors. Those choices may give strange results.

Comment: Also known as your setup does not compile at my end when I use TeXLive 2020 and a setup like yours. Never ignore compilation errors. The error I get is `! Undefined control sequence \gtt@chartextrasize{0 }{0.39998pt}`

Comment: don't you need `[time slot format =isodate-yearmonth]` if you use such dates?

Comment: Looks like I over-mwe'd this, will add back the lost texts

Comment: Alright, updated with a  less reduced example and the error message - thanks!

Comment: It looks like `subpreambles` isn't actually working, as adding `\usepackage{pgfgantt}` to the main document fixes it.

Comment: it does work, but not well enough. The code is executed after the aux file has been read and this is too late.

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion. So is this a bug in `standalone`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments this appears to be a bug in `standalone`. The class [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) mentions (page 23):

> The packages are loaded at the end of the preamble using the
> `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

This part of the manual is about the `sort` option, but the remark about loading packages applies also to the `subpreambles` option without `sort`.

This can be seen in the package code (around the middle of the file):

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\subpreamble\@gobble
  \let\endsubpreamble\relax
  \let\standalonepreambles\relax
  \let\endstandalonepreambles\relax
  \ifsa@sortsubpreambles
    \let\sa@orig@usepackage\usepackage
    \let\usepackage\sa@usepackagewithoutoptions
  \fi
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{}%
  \ifsa@sortsubpreambles
    \let\usepackage\sa@orig@usepackage
  \fi
  \immediate\openout\sa@out=\jobname.sta\relax
  \immediate\write\sa@out{\string\standalonepreambles}%
}
```

However, `\AtBeginDocument` is executed *after* the `.aux` file is read (see for example [When is the aux file read and written?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120973/when-is-the-aux-file-read-and-written)). To execute the code at the right time you can use `\AtEndPreamble` from the `etoolbox` package. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) (page 4):

> `\AtEndPreamble{<code>}` This hook differs from `\AtBeginDocument` in that
> the `<code>` is executed right at the end of the preamble,  before the
> main `aux` file (as written on the previous LaTeX pass) is read and prior
> to any `\AtBeginDocument` code.

You can check that this can indeed be used to address the issue by copying `standalone.sty` to the same directory as your document, adding `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}` to `standalone.sty`, and changing the mentioned occurrence of `\AtBeginDocument` to `\AtEndPreamble`.

It would be useful to add this (or an equivalent fix) to `standalone`.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>I was thinking about adding an issue to https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues but the Bitbucket issue tracker is read-only at the moment.</sub>